# Joomla Virtuemart show add cart to visitors

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am really new to Joomla and Virtue Mart and have inherited a working system.
I have a request to enable "Add To Cart" functionality to visitors.
Currently only logged in users can see this.

I have searched google, searched configuration settings, posted on the VirtueMart forum and re-downloaded the original Virtue Mart template to see if my predeccesor had done something dodgy.

Please help me allow visitors to add products into their shopping cart without the need to register.

I am running "VirtueMart 1.1.4 stable" on "Joomla! 1.5.17 Stable"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they did it through the VM setting, you need to go Components > Virtuemart > Admin > Configuration > Global > Membergroup to show prices to > Public Front-end.

You should also update to the latest version 1.5.20. The releases since 1.5.17 have all bee security releases.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. Will look into updating!

Comment: Glad to help. Take a look at Jupadateman for keeping your site up to date. Makes updating pretty painless. http://sammoffatt.com.au/os/joomla-15-products/3-jupdateman/36-jupdateman-introduction